# Delete multiple files based on partial names list

Tags: join, sed, redhat, comm

I have a folder one my Red Hat server with approx. 500k files from various extensions.
The name convention for those files is based on a number, for example:

- a**123456**.csv
- z**123456**.jpg
- **123456**.exe
- a**234**.jpg
- **234**.exe

I designed a query which produce a list of all the **numbers** that should be deleted.
Assuming i export this list daily/weekly into a txt file, what would be the most efficient way to delete all the files from the folders which appears in the list?

Running a for loop on every folder would take too long since there are too many files. I managed to produce a list of all the numbers to delete which have files in this folder using:

```
join <(cat list.txt | sort) <(ls /folder/with/0.5Mfiles | grep -v html$ | sed 's/[a-zA-Z.]*//g' | sort)
```

but that way I lose the original file name (e.g. z123456.jpg)

What could be the most efficient way to do it?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. What's in list.txt? Is that a list of filenames or a list of numbers?

Comment: It is a list of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
while read -r number; do
    echo rm /path/to/folder/*"$number"*
done < lists.txt
```

Remove "echo" if it looks OK

---

Yes, when `number=1234` then the pattern will match `a12345.jpg`. Let's try this:

```
$ shopt -s extglob nullglob
$ touch 1234 a1234 1234b c1234d 12345 a12345 12345b c12345d
$ number=1234
$ echo ?(*[^0-9])"$number"?([^0-9]*)
1234 1234b a1234 c1234d
```

the `?(...)` form *optionally* matches the contained pattern, and we use `*[^0-9]` and `[^0-9]*` to add a "number boundary" -- the preceding/following character must be a non-digit. So `?(*[^0-9])` matches *either* an empty string *or* a sequence of chars ending with a non-digit.

Comment: In case 1234 will be in lists.txt - 12345.jpg will also be deleted

Comment: Using a while is way too slow when dealing with some many files, I'm trying to come up with a solution using xargs

Comment: that would be `printf "%s\0" ?(*[^0-9])"$number"?([^0-9]*) | xargs -0 rm`